# Lesscss > bootstrap's darken() and lighten() don't compile

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, less

My Less files aren't compiling as they should. I'm using the Bootstrap less files, most recent ones.

It looks like the less-files are failing because of the  darken() and lighten() classes.

The error is:

> lessc fatal error: expected color value: failed at `background-color:
>   darken(@inputBackground, 1%);`
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/foobar/application/less/forms.less on line
>   195

When I go to that line, I find the darken() of lighten(), remove that and the error is gone. But a new error appears, also a line with the darken() of lighten() class. Strange, right, or isn't it? Is there a fix someone knows about? Because I don't wanna remove the lighten() and darken() everywhere, they're the nicest functions in Bootstrap less!

Saved the files to UTF8 without BOM already in SublimeText2

Edit: strange, it works when it's on my NAS. Not local on my MacBook.. Is it a OSX issue?

Comment: Are you sure you are compiling and modifying the right files on your local ? And check the `@inputBackground` value, since the error tells us that it's not a color. (note: 1%, really?)

Comment: Yes, I'm for sure. That are just Bootstrap standard values, don't know if I edited the 1% from 10% or not.

Comment: Actually, 1% is the default value, my bad. Can you try to compile a simple file with `.test { background-color: darken(#fff, 1%); }` ?

Answer (score 2):

My problems were solved once I changed the order of less file @import rules. The colour definition should be parsed before darken() is called.